# how to I create a derived column by aggregate data from another column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, derived

I have 2 tables :

```
Book(Name,quantity,supplier)
SuppliedBy (supplier,quantity)
```

I want the quantity in SuppliedBy table equal sum of the books supplied by that supplier, so I wrote a set statement

```
update supplier
set supplier.quantity = (select quantity 
                         from (select sum(quantity) as quantity, SuppliedBy 
                               from book group by SuppliedBy) a
                         where a.SuppliedBy = supplier.SuppliedBy)
```

However I want to automatically update quantity value in SuppliedBy when a new book is add. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a **after insert** trigger on Book table to update value in supliedBy table.

Comment: I tried this : CREATE TRIGGER quantity_Trigger after update on book
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  update supplier
set supplier.quantity = (select quantity 
                         from (select sum(quantity) as quantity, SuppliedBy 
                               from book group by SuppliedBy) a
                         where a.SuppliedBy = supplier.SuppliedBy)
END
GO                                                                                                               I got no change while add book, dunno if I get anything wrong

Comment: I think you should create after insert trigger, not after update. Please accept as answer if I'm correct :).